# Auto escape in python string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, escaping

I realised that python has some auto-escape mechanism for string when i exported my dataframe into a text file.

Dataframe

```
ID | Description 
1 | fruitsbaskets
2 | apple orange"pear
```

When i exported the dataframe in to a text file, the value of apple orange"pear was changed to "apple orange""pear". Python automatically added enclosing double quotes and an additional double quotes in my value.

May i know how do i prevent this from happening?
I want to export the dataframe as raw string - exporting apple orange"pear as it is.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: by default  `quotechar='"'`  so you can change that  to `quotechar="'"`  in `to_csv()` method so it looks like `df.to_csv('filename.txt',quotechar="'")`  but remember if data look like this `apple orange'pear` in that case you will have the same problem like you are facing now

Comment: but in this case: `apple orange'pear`  taking this `"` as convention you can replace all the `'` to `"` so this problem will also resolve

Comment: hi @AnuragDabas! Thanks for your suggestion. I'm ok to have enclosed double quotes. But i do not want to have additional double quote within the value. Any suggestions?

Comment: as I mention above you can  use `quotechar` parameter in `to_csv()` method so `apple orange"pear` will write as it is inside the text file

Comment: @AnuragDabas thanks! Found out that my issue arised from using quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL.